# How to download torrents from the command line?

Tags: command-line, bittorrent, transmission

I want to download a large file through bittorrent on my server. For doing this, I downloaded the [transmission command line client](https://github.com/fagga/transmission-remote-cli) and the relevant .torrent file on the server, and then I run the following command:

```
./transmission-remote-cli the_torrent_file.torrent
```

but I get the following error:

```
EXECUTING:
transmission-remote localhost:9091 -a the_torrent_file.torrent
RESPONSE:
Could not execute the above command: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I know 100% sure that the_torrent_file.torrent exists in the present directory (I even finished it by hitting tab). So which file or directory does not exist?

Any tips on downloading the torrent from the command line are very welcome!

Comment: Don't know, but you could try asking on on the Transmission forum. I have found them very responsive and helpful. The developers often answer directly. https://forum.transmissionbt.com/

Answer (score 4):

you can use `transmission-cli`:

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-cli
```

You can use `transmission-daemon` instead:

```
sudo apt-get install transmission-daemon
```

and then use these commands to manage it:

```
transmission-create
transmission-remove
transmission-edit
transmission-show
```